# How to use 'cover' option in pdfkit?

Tags: node.js, image, pdf, pdfkit, cover

I'm trying to make a pdf file with a list of images, one image per page. The image should cover the whole page and shouldn't be cropped. I don't want to use `fit` option cause i'll have to provide `width` and `height` and it will be a hassle. So I figured I should use `cover` option but I can't seem to figure out how to use it. I couldn't find the solution in the internet either. Even its [documentation](http://pdfkit.org/docs/images.html) doesn't mention about how to use it. I tried some random code like following:

```
doc.image('path/to/image.png', {
  cover: true
});
```

but no luck. It shows following error:

```
(node:9004) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: options.cover is not iterable
    at PDFDocument.image (/var/www/html/Custom Manga Downloader/node_modules/pdfkit/js/pdfkit.js:4487:26)
    at Object.run (/var/www/html/Custom Manga Downloader/downloaders/holymanga.net/index.mjs:21:7)
    at __holymanga (/var/www/html/Custom Manga Downloader/server.js:36:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/Custom Manga Downloader/server.js:42:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
```

Please, any help will be appreciated.

Thank You :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation page says:

> cover **array** provided - image is scaled proportionally to completely cover the rectangle defined by the passed width and height.

So, it actually needs an array of `[width, height]` instead of a `boolean`. Provide it an array and it will work perfectly fine.

Here's a snippet of what I am using:

```js
doc.image(`${url}-screenshot.png`, {
        cover: [doc.page.width - 100, doc.page.height - 300]
    });
```

Cheers!

Comment: It perfectly solved my problem. I need to turn the png forms into one pdf, each png is one pdf page.